# MongoDB Realm React Native SDK with Expo - Missing Realm Constructor error

Tags: mongodb, expo, mongodb-realm

According to the latest documentation for MongoDB Realm React Native, it states that their SDK is compatible with Expo...

> Expo now supports Realm with the Expo SDK version 44. To use Realm
> with Expo, upgrade to Expo SDK version 44. Realm does not work with
> earlier versions of Expo.

We have installed Expo and have the latest version of their SDK, however no matter what we try we get an error stating "Missing Ream Constructor":

[image]

We require the project to be in the Expo managed workflow and not the bare workflow.  When we setup in bare workflow, it works.

Are we missing something??

Comment: Did you look at the [Getting Started Template](https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-realm) and follow the [Setup Guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)? There's even handle blog post [Build an Offline-First React Native Mobile App with Expo and Realm](https://medium.com/realm/build-an-offline-first-react-native-mobile-app-with-expo-and-realm-e904cc883a51)

Comment: The blog link Jay posted led me to this [expo template](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/tree/master/templates/expo-template-js) in the realm repo. That's worth looking at for some things not mentioned in the documentation, namely the index.js contents. However, even cloning and running that template gives me the constructor error, so I opened [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/4332) on github

Comment: Just an update: a contributor replied to the issue I opened and said Realm does not have Expo Go app support. I don't know if you're using that, but he left some info on building a client on your test device.

Answer (score 0):

**Some of the settings I made to fix:**

> REMEMBER: `react-native-reanimated` doesn't work with **Realm & Expo**

Following the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/using-expo-realm-expo-dev-client/)

- Rather than run with `expo start` or `npx react-native [platform]` run `yarn android` for iOS or `yarn ios`
- Install Java SDK version 8
- Uninstall react-native: `npm uninstall -g react-native` and run `npx react-native run-android`

**If you got this error:**

`A problem occurred configuring project ':realm'.`

> Could not create task ':realm:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create task ':realm:forwardDebugPort'.
> > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\yourUser\Desktop\Projects\MyAwesomeRealmApp\android\local.properties'.
> `

**To fix this:**

- Create a file with the name `local.properties` in android directory
- Open the file and paste your Android SDK path like below: `sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this issue using
@realm/react: 0.4.3, realm: 11.8.0

Check your script for building for android in `package.json`.

In my case it was `expo start --android`, and changing it to `expo run:android` fixed the problem (must build app for Realm to work).

This is the command included in the official template for expo-realm found in npm.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@realm/expo-template?activeTab=code

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    ....
```

*haven't checked ios

Answer (score 0):

Run using `expo run:ios` or `expo run:android`